# How can I store data from a webapi like a DbContext DbSet in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, repository

I just followed this tutorial on loading json from a WebAPI into MVC: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-asp-net-web-api-rest-service-in-asp-net-mvc-using-http-client/

This all worked, but it only displays the data in the index page.

Im also using a DbContext for loading data directly from a database. The advantage of DbContexts is that the data gets stored in a DbSet which I can call at any time to get data.

I would like the same for the WebAPI data.

I have 2 endpoints containing information from 2 tables.

```
Items
-----------------------------------------------
| Id      | Name                | Material    |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1004    | Chain               | Gold        |
| 1402    | Vase                | Ceramic     |
-----------------------------------------------

Retailers
-----------------------------------------------
| Id      | Name                | City        |
-----------------------------------------------
| 3829    | StoreA              | New York    |
| 1827    | StoreB              | London      |
-----------------------------------------------
```

I can retrieve the information with `/api/items` and `/api/retailers`.

I currently have a DbContext for the other data, who use repositories to link the data from the DbContext to the Views.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: add the model, then add a DbSet<newModel> to the DbContext